# What am I doing wrong with bind9?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, vps, dns-zone

I am trying to bind a domain name to a vps but I am failing..

I get this when I dig:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ns1.example.com @61.15.2.95
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49520
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns1.example.com.        604800  IN  A   61.15.2.95

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.        604800  IN  NS  ns2.example.com.
example.com.        604800  IN  NS  ns1.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.example.com.        604800  IN  A   178.159.2.95

;; Query time: 314 msec
;; SERVER: 178.159.2.95#53(178.159.2.95)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 15 14:26:22 +04 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 106
```

**Problem**
`;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available`
since it is just a warning I tried to register it at quickhostuk but I got this error at dns management:

```
Failed to Modify Domain Nameservers: Nameserver not found at registry
```

here is what I did..

say, my vps IP is: **61.15.2.95** 
domain name: **example.com**
name servers:

- ns1.example.com=>61.15.2.95
- ns2.example.com =>61.15.2.95

1.I installed bind9.

2.I created a zone in **named.conf.local**

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
};
```

3. I created a db file for `db.example.com`

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. root.ns1.example.com. (
                              3         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                        604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@                IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
@                IN      NS      ns2.example.com.
@                IN      A       61.15.2.95
ns1              IN      A       61.15.2.95
ns2              IN      A       61.15.2.95
```

4.I modified **named.conf.options** and I added my vps ip to forwarders, I also tried google's `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        forwarders {
                61.15.2.95;
        };


        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

How should I correctly put it all together to make it work?

Comment: `What am I doing wrong with bind9?` Using it in the first place. There is usually no reason to run your own DNS server - about every domain registrar/reseller offers convenient methods to run your domain with their DNS infrastructure run by experts and unless you have very good reason not to, you should use this.

Answer (score 2):

`;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available` is actually a good sign when running an authoritative server, it is not supposed to provide recursion.
Instead of changing anything on the server side, you can simply add `+norec` to the `dig` command line to not request recursion and the warning will go away.

For an authoritative server you also do not need `forwarders`. You may actually want to go one step further and specify `recursion no` to be really sure you do not accidentally provide recursion access.

Regarding the problem, where you get the message `Failed to Modify Domain Nameservers: Nameserver not found at registry` in your interactions with your registrar I would guess that this has to do with the specific process of changing nameservers with this registrar.
As your nameserver names are inside your own zone, you will need glue records. I'm guessing that adding the necessary information for these glue records may be a separate step that you need to complete first.

Your question also suggests that you are using the same IP address for "two" nameservers. This sounds like a way to trick the enforcement of what is actually very sound policy of having some redundancy in place.

Finally, I will note that if you do not know how to run a nameserver and your end goal is something else altogether (running some other services), you are very likely better off using some established and properly managed dns hosting solution rather than setting up your own infrastructure for this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to host the entirety of your DNS on your own machine with one IP address, referencing your own domain as the DNS server.

You can't get there from here.

First, you need 2 DNS servers that resolve to different IPs.

If you want to name your dns server(s) ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com then you need to set up what is known as "glue records" with your registrar.  This will allow ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com to be the only dns servers for the example.com domain.

Once you have your glue records set, remove the forwarders from the /etc/bind/named.conf.options - you shouldn't need it unless you have clients querying your servers directly.